# How to programmatically set contact image in Outlook 2007?

Tags: image, contacts

How could we automatically/programmatically set the sender/contact image in outlook 2007?  They are colleagues, and all employees pictures are stored in netshare.

Answer (score 1):

I see that Outlook.ContactItem has an AddPicture method.  Here's an example straight out of the help file:

```
Sub AddPictureToAContact()
    Dim myNms As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myContactItem As Outlook.ContactItem
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strPrompt As String

    Set myNms = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNms.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    strName = InputBox("Type the name of the contact: ")
    Set myContactItem = myFolder.Items(strName)
    If myContactItem.HasPicture = True Then
        strPrompt = MsgBox("The contact already has a picture associated with it. Do you want to overwrite the existing picture?", vbYesNo)
        If strPrompt = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    strPath = InputBox("Type the file name for the contact: ")
    myContactItem.AddPicture (strPath)
    myContactItem.Save
    myContactItem.Display
 End Sub
```